# How can i claim moving expense in 1040?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction, moving

I moved over 200 miles last year to be close to my new working place, using a service found on an online app (Roadie).

Can i claim the moving expense in Line 26 in 1040? Do i need to provide to IRS a print out of the receipt of the moving expense?

Answer (score 2):

[Yes](https://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tools/tax-tips/General-Tax-Tips/IRS-Moving-Expense-Deductions/INF14389.html) you can deduct it:

> Federal tax laws allow you to deduct your moving expenses if your
>   relocation relates to starting a new job or a transfer to a new
>   location for your present employer. To qualify for the deduction, your
>   new work location must be a sufficient distance from your old home and
>   you must begin working shortly after you arrive.

According to the [IRS](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p521/ar01.html):

> It is important to maintain an accurate record of expenses you paid to
>   move. You should save items such as receipts, bills, canceled checks,
>   credit card statements, and mileage logs. Also, you should save your
>   Form W-2 and statements of reimbursement from your employer.

You don't need to present them with the receipts when you file, but it's good to have them in case they question your tax return and ask for more documentation.

Comment: Thanks. Last year I moved more than 200 miles to work for my previous employer, not my present employer. Is it okay?

Comment: In terms of distance, as long as the "distance between your new job and your former home must be at least 50 miles farther than your previous employer is from that home" then you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

In order to claim the moving expense deduction, you must meet three criteria:

- The move must be closely related (in time and place) to starting a new job.
- You must meet the distance test.
- You must meet the time test.

The move is considered closely related in time to your new job if the expenses are incurred within a year of starting your new job.  It is closely related in place if you have moved closer to your new job.

The distance test says that the distance between your new job and your old home must be 50 miles more than the distance between your old job and your old home.

The time test means that in the 12 months following your move, you must be employed full time at least 39 weeks.  The 39 weeks needs to be in the general area of your new home, but they do not need to be with the same employer.

If you meet all three of these criteria, you should be able to take the moving expense deduction.

More details from IRS:

- [Tax Topic 455 - Moving Expenses](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc455.html)
- [Publication 521 - Moving Expenses](https://www.irs.gov/uac/about-publication-521)
- [Can I Deduct My Moving Expenses?](https://www.irs.gov/uac/can-i-deduct-my-moving-expenses)

To claim the moving expense deduction, use [Form 3903](https://www.irs.gov/uac/about-form-3903).  You do not send in any receipts, but you need to keep receipts so that you can prove the expenses in the event that your return is audited.